# Filling a constructor with a loop

Tags: c#, for-loop, parameters, constructor

I'm dealing with an object with 7 parameters, and these 7 parameters all represent a day in the week. If the day is Monday, then the remaining 6 days in the constructor is supposed to be filled with null.

I start by creating an object and fill all 7 parameters in the constructor with null, but my question is: How do I create a loop that fills the correct amount of days? The problem is not getting current day, nor using setters, but I can't really crack the code on how to use a loop this way.

```
Week week = new Week(null, null, null, null, null, null, null);

for (int i=0; i<7; i++) {
    week(set first parameter, then second, then third etc)..
}
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Is `Week` code you can modify? It looks like a better constructor would be in order, maybe one that takes just a `System.DayOfWeek` object...

Comment: [`DateTime.DayOfWeek`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.dayofweek(v=vs.110).aspx) enum should be your best choice. You can use values from the enum to determine each constructor argument when creating `Week` instance.

Comment: what a weird class design..

Comment: Actually this is just a thought example of my project, to simplify. My parameters consists of Thickness objects but i thought that wasnt relevant. I just need to figure out how to access a parameter by number of some somrt (like access parameter [7].. for the loop

Comment: that is called indexing and in its simplest form could use a `System.Array`

Comment: I am accessing data from an array.. I mean, i just need to modify a constructor to receive data by index. I cant fill a single object by using System.Array..

Comment: you can't fill constructor with a loop, however, if the parameters are available as properties, you can use reflection to set their values within a loop

Comment: I don´t understand this design at all. "and these 7 parameters all represent a day in the week. If the day is monday" If you have seven days, what is "the day"? Apart from this why should one create instancaes of a week? Isn´t a week something static with allways the exact same days? I can´t see why one would ever create a `Week(Monday, Monday, Monday, Monday, Monday)` and later in the program a `Week(Sunday, Sunday, Sunday, Sunday)`.

Comment: @AshkanMobayenKhiabani interesting! Thanks for the answer

Comment: @HimBromBeere This is a thought example, sorry for not clarifying. The exercise is to fill a constructor using a loop. The project that i am working at is too complex to even start elaborating here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because of your comments I thought:
You should consider using optional parameters where you can set a default value for a parameter which can be null.

Pseudocode:

```
public week(object param1 = null, object param2 = null, object param3 = null)
{
    //Do Stuff here
}
```

So you can call the constructor with leaving some arguments empty. But be warned that this is not considered a clean solution especially when the type of the parameters is all the same because that might cause some trouble.

You will find more information about optional parameters [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/named-and-optional-arguments#optional-arguments).

Comment: I ended up filling empty spots with a for loop, but this is a great solution aswell!

Answer (score 0):

You can convert day of week to integer like this and implement your logic..

```
int day = (int)DateTime.Now.DayOfWeek;
```

Remember First day of the week: Sunday (with a value of zero). You can handle it and set its value to 7..

```
int day = ((int)DateTime.Now.DayOfWeek == 0) ? 7 : (int)DateTime.Now.DayOfWeek;
```

Comment: Ah this could very much be it. Do i understand this right, if i type ? i can figure out if it is null and then set it to another value?

Comment: You can compare day int with the var in for loop to identify the day

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a broken design. Why would one ever create an instance of a `Week`? I can´t imagine any usecase to do such a thing, as a `Week` seems like a quite static thing to me.

Anyway to answer your question about the constructor there´s no way to fill the parameters of a method or constructor one by one, you have to set all at ones.

You could of course set the properties of your class one after the other:

```
Week w = new Week();
var props = typeof(Week).GetProperties();
for(int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
{
    // set properties, e.g. using reflection:
    props[i].SetValue(w, myValue);
}
```